# Trying to get user email storage from google admin api

Tags: node.js, google-api

I am building a little script, that access the Google Reseller api that gets all the domains, then finds the users in those domains, to which it then looks at the emails for those users. That part all works.

The issue is that after I have gotten the users emails, I need to check the email storage so that I can then send an alert once the storage is nearly full.

I have searched the internet and tried various different methods, but seem to have hit a roadblock with the final step.

This is as far a I got with code

```
let privatekey = require("./spartan-concord-344213-d46691ffcd02.json");
let spreadsheetPriKey = require("./spreadsheet_service_account.json");


const {JWT} = require('google-auth-library');

// configure a JWT auth client
let jwtClient = new JWT({
    email: privatekey.client_email,
    key: privatekey.private_key,
    subject: 'subject@email.com',
    scopes:['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.order',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly', 
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.usage.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly',
],
});

let jwtSpreadsheetClient = new JWT({
    email: spreadsheetPriKey.client_email,
    key: spreadsheetPriKey.private_key,
    scopes:['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'],
});

const sites = []
//authenticate request
jwtSpreadsheetClient.authorize(async function (err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } else {
        google.options({ auth: jwtSpreadsheetClient });
        const client = google.sheets({ version: "v4" });
        const supportEmail = await client.spreadsheets.values.get({ spreadsheetId: 'ID', range:'Sites!C2:C',});
      let suppEmails = supportEmail.data.values;
suppEmails.forEach(element => {
 if(element[0] != null){
    sites.push(element[0]);
 }
});





    }
});


//authenticate request
jwtClient.authorize(async function (err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } else {
      google.options({ auth: jwtClient });
   const service = google.reseller({version: 'v1'});
const res = await service.customers.get({
                'customerId': 'testDomain',
            });
        // console.log(res);
     const services = google.admin({version: 'directory_v1'});
  respo = await services.users.get({
    userKey: 'test@email.com',
    projection: 'FULL',
    viewType: 'admin_view'
  });
       // console.log(respo);

      
  const servicess = google.admin({version: 'reports_v1'});
// const response = await servicess.userUsageReport.get({
//   userKey: 'all',
//   date: '2022-10-11',
//   parameters: 'gmail:is_gmail_enabled',
//    customerId: 'customerId'
//   });

const response = await servicess.activities.list({
    userKey: 'all',
    applicationName: 'drive',
    maxResults: 10,
   customerId: 'customerId'
  });
            console.log(response.data);
      
    }
});
```

Any information is much appreciated :)

Comment: how can you see a user's storage limit normally?  what system stores that data?

Comment: @DaImTo Well, I am not sure via code. However via ui I go to my google admin as an overall admin, then I go to reseller tools, select the customer domain, then go to admin console for that customers workspace, then I go to users, find the user and look at their storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you can get this information from the Reports API via [userUsageReport.get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/userUsageReport/get) with a delay.

Which provides the following useful Account Parameters with `applicationName=accounts`.

- `drive_used_quota_in_mb`
- `gmail_used_quota_in_mb`
- `gplus_photos_used_quota_in_mb`
- `total_quota_in_mb`
- `used_quota_in_mb`
- `used_quota_in_percentage`

Found [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/user/accounts).

```js
const { JWT } = require('google-auth-library');
const keys = require('./jwt.keys.json');

async function main() {
    const client = new JWT({
        email: keys.client_email,
        key: keys.private_key,
        scopes: [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.usage.readonly'
        ],
    });

    const userKey = 'example@gmail.com';
    const threeDaysAgo = new Date();
    threeDaysAgo.setDate(new Date().getDate() - 3);
    const date = datethreeDaysAgo.toISOString().split('T').slice(0, 1)[0]
    const url = `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/usage/users/${userKey}/dates/${date}?parameters=accounts:used_quota_in_percentage,accounts:total_quota_in_mb,accounts:used_quota_in_mb,accounts:drive_used_quota_in_mb,accounts:gmail_used_quota_in_mb,accounts:gplus_photos_used_quota_in_mb`;
    const res = await client.request({ url });
    console.log(res.data);
    /*
    {
      "kind": "admin#reports#usageReports",
      "etag": "\"iOcWZfmq3FoTN4bnM3qjxTbCKtrhwribSW4KdcAqWMQ/jldXIL3cW34P49N2Row7rqWkykQ\"",
      "usageReports": [
        {
          "kind": "admin#reports#usageReport",
          "date": "2022-10-17",
          "etag": "\"iOcWZfmq3FoTN4bnM3qjxTbCKtrhwribSW4KdcAqWMQ/vroqtrwJo5ZJIWScePvwODh5ZGI\"",
          "entity": {
            "type": "USER",
            "customerId": "FVdfugb32",
            "userEmail": "example@gmail.com",
            "profileId": "2350766532076257332587"
          },
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "accounts:used_quota_in_percentage",
              "intValue": "0"
            },
            {
              "name": "accounts:total_quota_in_mb",
              "intValue": "-1"
            },
            {
              "name": "accounts:used_quota_in_mb",
              "intValue": "858"
            },
            {
              "name": "accounts:drive_used_quota_in_mb",
              "intValue": "461"
            },
            {
              "name": "accounts:gmail_used_quota_in_mb",
              "intValue": "397"
            },
            {
              "name": "accounts:gplus_photos_used_quota_in_mb",
              "intValue": "0"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
    */
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: I have tried running your script, but I keep getting this error 
Caller does not have access to the customers reporting data.

Comment: @YuriAlves you'll need to ensure that your API client has authenticated with the necessary scopes. I haven't tested this code I'm just going by the examples in the documentation.

The output you see is from me testing the method via the API explorer provided in the documentation.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/userUsageReport/get?apix=true